# d3dxcompileshaderfromfile versus d3dxcreatetexturefromfile

Tags: graphics, directx

I can use D3DXCreateTextureFromFile fine but was wondering what D3DXCompileTextureFromFile is and its purpouses, it seems to be basically the same thing? However I"m unsure how to use it properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say D3DXCompile "Texture" FromFile in your post body, I will assume you mean D3DXCompileShaderFromFile. That function compiles shader code, which is a variation of C that is compiled specifically to run on the GPU, per vertex or per pixel. D3DXCreateTextureFromFile creates a texture, which can be used by a shader for any number of purposes but is usually used for texturing, which is described quite well [in this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping).